# Uses only half the page / Right side of the page empty

Tags: blank-page, emptypage, empty-line

I'm very new to Tex, I'm trying to write an algorithm using LaTeX on Overleaf but only the left half of the page is used while the rest of the line is sent to the next line.

[image]

Can you tell me what did I do wrong ?

```
 \documentclass{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 %\begin{algorithm}
 %\caption{Algorithm for ...}
 \textbf{Algorithm:GraphPaths(capital,Cryptocurrencies[])}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
 \REQUIRE capital, Cryptocurrencies [];
 \ENSURE  Augmenting paths and total arbitrage
 \\ \textit{Initialisation} :
 \STATE Path = [];
\FOR {$i$ in $Currencies$ }
    \WHILE{$Currencies_i.market[0]$\textless$Currencies_i.market[n]$:}
        \STATE volume = min($market_i_0$, $market_i_n$, $capital$);
        \STATE $market_i_0$, $market_i_n$-=volume;
        \IF {capital\textgreater volume}
            \STATE capital = capital-volume+volume\cdot($market_i_n.price$- $market_i_0.price$);
        \ELSE capital+=volume\cdot($market_i_n$.price - $market_i_0$.price);
        \STATE Path.add{$Currencies_i.market[0]$,$Currencies_i.market[n]$}
        \IF {$market.volume$ $\leq$ 0 in $Currencies$:}
            \STATE remove: $.market[x]$;
 
\ENDFOR

 \RETURN {Path, capital}
 \end{algorithmic} 
 %\end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Are you referring to what happens after `do` and `else`?  Otherwise, I'm not seeing what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why the line is cut in half (on the pdf it stops in the middle of the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from not closing the structures within your algorithm. That is, `\IF`s should have a closing `\ENDIF`, `\WHILE`s should have a closing `\ENDWHILE` and `\FOR`s should have a closing `\ENDFOR`. Additionally, you can't have double subscripts of the form `a_b_c`; instead you're probably after `a_{b_c}`. Finally, `\cdot` is a math symbol and can therefore only be used within `$`...`$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\newcommand{\NONUMSTATE}{\item[]}
\newcommand{\VAR}{\textnormal}
\newcommand{\minusbecomes}{\mathrel{{-}{=}}}
\newcommand{\plusbecomes}{\mathrel{{+}{=}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{Algorithm: GraphPaths(capital,Cryptocurrencies [])}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \REQUIRE capital, Cryptocurrencies [];
  \ENSURE  Augmenting paths and total arbitrage
  
  \NONUMSTATE \textit{Initialisation}:
  
  \STATE Path = [];
  \FOR {$i$ in $\VAR{Currencies}$}
    \WHILE{$i.\VAR{market}[0] < .\VAR{market}[n]$}
      \STATE $\VAR{volume} = \min(\VAR{market}_{i_0}, \VAR{market}_{i_n}, \VAR{capital})$;
      \STATE $\VAR{market}_{i_0}, \VAR{market}_{i_n} \minusbecomes \VAR{volume}$;
      \IF {$\VAR{capital} > \VAR{volume}$}
        \STATE $\VAR{capital} \plusbecomes 
          \VAR{capital} - \VAR{volume} + \VAR{volume} \cdot (\VAR{market}_{i_n}.\VAR{price} - \VAR{market}_{i_0}.\VAR{price})$;
      \ELSE
        \STATE $\VAR{capital} \plusbecomes \VAR{volume} \cdot (\VAR{market}_{i_n}.\VAR{price} - \VAR{market}_{i_0}.\VAR{price})$;
      \ENDIF
      \STATE Path.add $i.\VAR{market}[0], i.\VAR{market}[n]$
      \IF {$\VAR{market}.\VAR{volume} \leq 0$ in $\VAR{Currencies}$}
        \STATE remove $.\VAR{market}[x]$;
      \ENDIF
    \ENDWHILE
  \ENDFOR

  \RETURN Path, capital
\end{algorithmic} 

\end{document}
```

I've also introduces some minor changes to your coding style, just to provide consistency.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think my mistake was to use the "-" symbol from my keyboard that seems to be an incorrect way to do subtraction in LaTeX.

I used \textminus and it worked perfectly, it was really a newbie issue, I hope that helps anyone facing in the same issue.